# Parameterized Stored Procedure in Access 2010

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have a database running on SQL Server and I have created some forms in Access 2003. Some of the forms call stored procedures and functions which prompt you for the required parameters. Access 2003 automatically pops up a box that asks me for the parameters then either returns the results or inserts the data. Access 2010 won't prompt me for the parameters, it just gives me an error saying missing required parameter or something. I've heard people say I need to create a pass through query. I tried this but couldn't get anything to work without hard coding the parameters.

Why does Access 2003 prompt for parameters and Access 2010 doesn't? Do I need to rewrite these procedures and functions?

Comment: can you share your query or the stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Try working your way through this.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/use-a-parameter-to-make-a-query-ask-for-input-HA010341833.aspx